# Access child property from parent scope

Tags: php, oop

I need a parent class to access its child properties:

```
class Parent {
  private $_fields = null;

  public function do_something() {
    // Access $_fields and $child_var here
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  private $child_var = 'hello';
}

$child = new Child();
$child->do_something();
```

When `$_fields` is modified from the child scope, it's still `null` in the parent scope. When trying to access $child_var from parent scope using `$this->child_var`, it's of course undefined.

I didn't find anything like a "function set" that would just be copied in the child class...

Comment: You probably want to make properties `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at an article about [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Basically, you cannot access parent's `private` properties/methods nor can the parent access its child's. However, you can declare your property/method `protected` instead.

```
class Parent {
    protected $_fields = null;

    public function do_something() {
        // Access $_fields and $child_var here
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    protected $child_var = 'hello';
}

$child = new Child();
$child->do_something();
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was exactly what i was looking for. Seems that I didn't read that documentation enough.

Answer (score 12):

Trying to access child values from base(parent) class is a bad design. What if in the future someone will create another class based on your parent class, forget to create that specific property you are trying to access in your parent class?

If you need to do something like that you should create the property in a parent class, and then set it in child:

```
class Parent 
{
    protected $child_var;

    private $_fields = null;    
    public function do_something() 
    {     
        // Access $_fields and $child_var here
        //access it as $this->child_var   
    }
}
class Child extends Parent 
{   
    $child_var = 'hello'; 
}  

$child = new Child(); 
$child->do_something();
```

Basically in parent you should not reference child-specific content, because you can't be sure it will be there!

If you have to, you should use abstraction:

[PHP Abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: Well, I know it's a bad practice, but its a very specific case that really requires it. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I understand the problem, but this solution is still looking to me risky. How can we enforce child class to define a certain property ? I have a concrete function in abstract parent class which requires a certain property. Right now i am using $this->childProperty in parent class and it runs but same issue that you highlighted.

Comment: You can make the `$child_var` abstract. this would enforce any children to actually implement it.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk properties cannot be declared abstract.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk - lets say there exists a class called `GoalSharedModel` that extends the parent class `ParentSharedModel`.  Lets also say there exists `GoalTypeSharedModel` that extends the same parent class.  The child shared models are dynamically populated based on database fields thereby the instantiated fields are always different.  HOWEVER, you want to be able to reflect (recursively) and return `GoalSharedModel.Name` and `GoalTypeSharedModel.Code` and you didn't want to write that in every shared model.  This is a good example of a use case I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of answers are not correct !!!!!....notice that you create an object from child class outside of bout classes....so you can access to the parent method (if parent method be public).....and here from inside of parent method you can access to the parent_fields (parent fields should be private because of encapsulation ) and child_fields (child fields should be protected because now you are in parent method)

```
class Parentclass {
    private $parent_fields = "parent field";

    public function do_something() {
        // Access $_fields and $child_var here
        echo $this->parent_fields.PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->child_fields;
    }
}

class Child extends Parentclass {
    protected $child_fields = 'child field';
}

$child = new Child();
$child->do_something();
```