# "this" in class inheritance, PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

I am new to PHP and got two questions. When I tried the following code:

```
<?php
class Base{
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
};


class Derived extends Base{
   public $id = 1;

   public function id(){
       return $this->id;
   }

};


$d1 = new Derived();

echo $d1->id();//echo 1
echo $d1->getId();//echo 1
?>
```

The code above would echo two 1's.

However, when I tried the following code:

```
<?php
class Base{
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
};


class Derived extends Base{
    private $id = 1;
    public function id(){
        return $this->id;
    }
};

$d1 = new Derived();

echo $d1->id();//echo 1
echo $d1->getId();//Cannot access private property Derived::$id
?>
```

The second function call will give me an error "Cannot access private property Derived::$id". So my question is what is $this in Base referred to when I made $d1->getId()?

I am quite confused in that if $this refers to the d1 instance, then it should be able to access the private $id. However, if $this refers to the Base inside $d1, then how can it get the $id property from Derived class? Thanks!

Comment: `id()` method is redundant: it does the same as inherited `getId()` method

Comment: Because `$id` is private in the Derived class it is not accessible in the Base class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469759/access-child-property-from-parent-scope

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Your link seems like a possible duplicate to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, It looks like it

Comment: Never use in a base class something that was not defined in the base class. A class should only ever use instance properties and methods that it defined or inherited.

Comment: why do you complicate this? I think you confused yourself by using `id` for both a class variable `$id / $this->id` and for a class function `id() / $this->id()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is what is $this in Base referred to when I made
>   $d1->getId()?

`$this` is an instance of the instantiated object that was created with the `new` keyword of whatever class - it's not the class itself, it's an *instance* of that class. In your case, because you created `$d1` with `new Derived()`, `$this` is an instance of Derived.  Base doesn't have access to Derived's private property because base private properties are *exclusive* to the class that defined them. They do not share with inherited classes.

> how can it get the $id property from Derived class?

You're looking for *protected* visibility:

```
<?php
class Base{
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
};


class Derived extends Base{
    protected $id = 1;
    public function id(){
        return $this->id;
    }
};

$d1 = new Derived();

echo $d1->id();
echo $d1->getId();
?>
```

Protected visibility shares with other classes that are inherited with it.

*However* expecting a property to exist on a derived class is bad practice. You cannot guarantee that the derived class specifies that property. You might consider defining the base as abstract and checking for its existence.

Comment: So when I called $d1->getId(), $this in getId function is the base instance created inside $d1?

Comment: No, `$this` is an instance of Derived (because you created it with `new Derived()`). Derived just inherits methods from Base, but that doesn't mean the Base gets private-level access to Derived, they're still separate classes.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 1):

The private modifier indicates that the class property will only be accessible from within that class. Any subclasses or superclasses will be unable to access that property.

In your example $id is private to your Derived class, and therefore cannot be accessed by the Base class.

Answer (score -1):

Use protected instead of private as visibility.

Private means that your attribute is only accessible in the current object while protected is accessible to parent and childs elements.

Comment: That might solve the problem but it does not really answer the question.

Comment: I would like to... But I can't edit my answer!

Comment: That's strange, no idea why you wouldn't be able to edit your own answer...

Comment: And now I can... I suppose there is a tempo' or something before I can edit.